# Doctrine wrapInTransaction not persisting

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Making use of Doctrine v2.12.2 on PHP8.1 with MySQL5.7.38 database, attempting to persist data entity with  `wrapInTransaction` method inside of `setValue` function defined below; my understanding is that upon successful completion of the `wrapInTransaction` method that the entity should exist in the database; when debugging and stepping through, the `AccountSettingModelImpl` entity object has all the correct data populated in the fields but never seeing the entry in the database. This method is getting called multiple times to set the data; but my assumption is that because it is not being stored, when the `fetchSettingByKey` is called, an error is returned which then falls into the catch where Doctrine is attempting to create the entity again and throwing the 'Duplicate entry' exception.

The peculiar thing is that some values are getting stored in the database, but it seems that the php request must complete successfully for that to occur. Is there a setting that must be enabled for `wrapInTransaction` to persist immediately?

```
/**
 * Class SettingModel
 * @package kor\classes\models
 * @Entity @Table(name="korAccountSettings")
 */
class AccountSettingModelImpl extends AbstractBaseModel implements AccountSettingModel
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="AccountModelImpl")
     * @JoinColumn(name="asAccountId", referencedColumnName="aId")
     * @var AccountModelImpl
     */
    private AccountModel $account;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(name="asKey", type="text")
     * @var string
     */
    private string $key;

    /**
     * @Column(name="asVal", type="text", nullable=true)
     * @var mixed
     */
    private ?string $val;

    /**
     * @Column(name="asUpdated", type="datetime_immutable")
     * @var DateTime
     */
    private DateTimeInterface $updated;
}
```

```
public function setValue(string $sKey, $sVal)
    {
        Application::getEntityManager()->wrapInTransaction(function (EntityManager $entityManager)
        use ($sKey, $sVal) {
            $accountModel = $this->getAccountModel();
            try {
                $settingModel = AccountSettingHelper::fetchSettingByKey($sKey, $accountModel);
                $settingModel->setVal($sVal);
                if(is_null($sVal) && $entityManager->contains($settingModel))
                    $entityManager->remove($settingModel);
            } catch (SettingNotFoundException $e) {
                $settingModel = Application::newEntity(AccountSettingModel::class);
                $settingModel->setAccount($accountModel);
                $settingModel->setKey($sKey);
                $settingModel->setVal($sVal);
                $entityManager->persist($settingModel);
            }
        });
        return $sVal;
    }
```

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: Duplicate entry '1-rl.enabled' for key 'PRIMARY'
#0 OR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Connection.php(1814): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\API\MySQL\ExceptionConverter->convert() 
#1 OR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Connection.php(1749): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->handleDriverException() 
#2 OR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Statement.php(184): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->convertExceptionDuringQuery() 
#3 OR\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Statement.php(221): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->execute() 
#4 OR\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister.php(278): Doctrine\DBAL\Statement->executeStatement() 
#5 OR\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(1129): Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\Entity\BasicEntityPersister->executeInserts() 
#6 OR\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php(426): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->executeInserts() 
#7 OR\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(398): Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->commit() 
#8 OR\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php(269): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$entityManager->flush()` to trigger the commit to the database.

This probably happens somewhere else in your code and thus triggers the behavior you describe.